# Why won't my function tally up a score properly?

Tags: jquery, function

My question is simple, I have a few lines of code that should be tallying up my total score when the right input is selected. However, I can't seem to get the score to be anything but 0. Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(main);

function main(){
    $("input").hide();
    $("h1").on('click', function(){
        $('h1').css("background-color", "red")

    });

    var questions = [
        {
            question: "What is the capital of Washington?", choices: ["Salem", "Seattle",
            "Helena", "Olympia"], correctanswer: "Olympia"
        },
        {
            question: "How many countries are in Europe?", choices: ["15", "46", "27",
            "51"], correctanswer: "51"
        },

        {
            question: "What is the population of Mexico City?", choices: ["3.3 Million", "800 Thousand", "15.1 Million",
            "8.9 Million"], correctanswer: "8.9 Million"
        },

        {
            question: "Who is the current leader of Russia?", choices: ["Boris Yelstin", "Dmitry Medvedev",
            "Nikolai Bulganin", "Vladimir Putin"], correctanswer: "Vladimir Putin"
        },

        {
            question: "How large is the state of California?", choices: ["85,115 square miles", "130,919 square miles",
            "215,355 sqaure miles", "163,696 square miles"], correctanswer: "163,696 square miles"
        }
    ];

    $("#start").on('click', function() {
        $("#start").hide();
        $("input").show();
        quiz();

    } );


    total=0;
    number=0;

    function quiz(){
        $("#question").text(questions[number].question);
        $("#answer1").text(questions[number].choices[0]);
        $("#answer2").text(questions[number].choices[1]);
        $("#answer3").text(questions[number].choices[2]);
        $("#answer4").text(questions[number].choices[3]);
    }


 $("#submit").on('click', function(){
     var chosen;
     chosen = ($("input[name='choice']:checked").val());
     if (chosen == questions[number].correctanswer) {
         total++;
         $("#score").text("Score: " + total);
     } else {
         $("#score").text("Score: " + total);
     }
     number++;
     quiz();

 });

}
```

```css
.btns{height:50px; width:80px; background-color:blue;
}

#answers{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Simple Quiz</h1>
<div id="question"></div>
<div id=answers>
    <input type="radio"  name="choice" value="1"><label id="answer1"></label><br>
    <input type="radio"  name="choice" value="2"><label id="answer2"></label><br>
    <input type="radio"  name="choice" value="3"><label id="answer3"></label><br>
    <input type="radio"  name="choice" value="4"><label id="answer4"></label><br>
</div>


<div id="btns">
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="score"><p></p></div>
```

So it's pretty simple as far as code goes and to me it looks like it should work, but clearly not so any help is appreciated. Thanks! Here's the git [repository](https://github.com/Zach94/SQ2-Final).

Comment: Have you validated the value of chosen?

Comment: Use the F12 debugger to step through the code. Inspect the variable values at each line. Which variable is mean to hold the score or are you just saving directly to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value attributes of your radio buttons are 1..4, and so this line evaluates to 1..4:

```
chosen = ($("input[name='choice']:checked").val());
```

You are then comparing 1..4 to a string value, such as Olympia, from your array:

```
if (chosen == questions[number].correctanswer) {
```

The integer is never equal to the string and so this condition never evaluates to true to increment your counter:

```
if (chosen == questions[number].correctanswer) {
total++;
```

To compare the string value to the string value (instead of its index) you want this:

```
chosen = ($("input[name='choice']:checked").val());
chosen = chosen - 1;
chosen = questions[number].choices[chosen];
```

Here is a jsfiddle that shows it working this way:
https://jsfiddle.net/79rfjz04/

Answer (score 1):

The `quiz()` function updates the text of each radio button, but not its value. So `chosen` will just be a number from 1 to 4, and won't match the `.correctanswer` property. Use the value as an index into the `choices` array and compare with that. I've changed the values of the radio buttons to start at `0`, to match array indexing.

Another way to fix it would be to change the `correctanswer` property to just contain the index of the correct answer, rather than its text.

```js
$(document).ready(main);

function main() {
  $("input").hide();
  $("h1").on('click', function() {
    $('h1').css("background-color", "red")

  });

  var questions = [{
      question: "What is the capital of Washington?",
      choices: ["Salem", "Seattle", "Helena", "Olympia"],
      correctanswer: "Olympia"
    }, {
      question: "How many countries are in Europe?",
      choices: ["15", "46", "27", "51"],
      correctanswer: "51"
    },

    {
      question: "What is the population of Mexico City?",
      choices: ["3.3 Million", "800 Thousand", "15.1 Million", "8.9 Million"],
      correctanswer: "8.9 Million"
    },

    {
      question: "Who is the current leader of Russia?",
      choices: ["Boris Yelstin", "Dmitry Medvedev", "Nikolai Bulganin", "Vladimir Putin"],
      correctanswer: "Vladimir Putin"
    },

    {
      question: "How large is the state of California?",
      choices: ["85,115 square miles", "130,919 square miles", "215,355 sqaure miles", "163,696 square miles"],
      correctanswer: "163,696 square miles"
    }
  ];

  $("#start").on('click', function() {
    $("#start").hide();
    $("input").show();
    quiz();
  });

  total = 0;
  number = 0;

  function quiz() {
    $("#question").text(questions[number].question);
    $("#answer1").text(questions[number].choices[0]);
    $("#answer2").text(questions[number].choices[1]);
    $("#answer3").text(questions[number].choices[2]);
    $("#answer4").text(questions[number].choices[3]);
    $("input[name='choice']:checked").prop("checked", false); // Clear the previous selection
  }

  $("#submit").on('click', function() {
    var chosen;
    chosen = questions[number].choices[$("input[name='choice']:checked").val()];
    if (chosen == questions[number].correctanswer) {
      total++;
      $("#score").text("Score: " + total);
    } else {
      $("#score").text("Score: " + total);
    }
    number++;
    quiz();
  });
}
```

```css
#btns {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#answers {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Simple Quiz</h1>
<div id="question"></div>
<div id=answers>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="0">
  <label id="answer1"></label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1">
  <label id="answer2"></label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="2">
  <label id="answer3"></label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="3">
  <label id="answer4"></label>
  <br>
</div>


<div id="btns">
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="score">
  <p></p>
</div>
```